# Angularjs: external url in directive's template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create a directive that would set a correct url referenced from the directive's template.

```
  datsApp.directive('myDir', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {},
            link: function (scope) {
                scope.url = link;
            },
            template: "<span>Click <a href='{{url}}'>here</a> for more info</span>"
        };
    });
```

The link variable is a global variable that holds a url and depends on the language and some other settings.

If I set link = 'www.google.com', I get it pointing to localhost:8888/somedir/www.google.com

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding an absolute address, start with http://whatever.address. This is because when you are adding the link without any Slash or without defining the protocol, the url is understood as a relative address. It is relative to your current location. This is why the Google.com is being appended to your current url

Comment: Thank you! Such a silly mistake - but now I have learned smth new :)